# Как настроить отдельный терминал Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, консоль, терминал

Что прописать в настройках запуска, чтобы консоль открывалась как отдельное окно?

Answer (score 4):

В IntelliJ IDEA вы можете управлять состоянием всех окон интерфейса с помощью инструмента управления состояния окна (шестеренка с стрелочкой), который находится в правой части заголовка окна.

Для того, чтобы открепить окно и сделать его самостоятельным нужно выбрать режим *Windowed Mode*

[image: scrn]

Так же доступны другие режимы:

- *Floating Mode* - то же, что и *Windowed Mode*, но в панели задач Windows не появляется собственной иконки значка этого отделенного окна.
- *Pinned Mode* -   окно остается видимым, когда не активно.
- *Docked Mode* -   прикрепление к другим элементам интерфейса.
- *Split Mode* -   состыковывываются несколько окон или показывается по одному.

[Официальная справка](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/viewing-modes.html) по режимам отображения окон

Comment: А в терминале ос нельзя ?

Comment: Думаю, если вы запустите IDEA через терминал ОС, то она будет выводить в терминал ОС. Другой вопрос - какая в этом необходимость, этот терминал точно такой же, только открыт сразу в нужном месте ..

Comment: я использую `Lanterne` и мне нужно четко видеть все элементы. К тому же в терминале `IDEA` вроде бы нельзя выводить разноцветный текст